# How add conditional Instalation Targets in manifest file in Visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Using single manifest file i am generating two vsix. One will target 2022 version and other will target 2019 and before. The problem is if i double click on 2022 vsix or 2019 vsix, both are listing all visual studio targeted versions like this
[image]

Liek above it displaying all visual studio version if it's installed. I trying to taget one vsix file for 2019 and 2017. and other vsix for 2022.

[image]

I am trying to add conditon like this but it's not working. Is this the right way to add condtion ot is any other ways are there.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to add conditon like this but it's not working. Is this
> the right way to add condtion ot is any other ways are there.

What is the aim of you? The version that the vsix can be installed in is decided by the Version property, why there are various verions available is because the version and condition all pass.

If you don't want a specific version be able to install this extension, just use false or make the condition false by some means in condition property.